# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have created a simple Wordcount Java-Flink program, below is the code:

```
public class Wordcount {
    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception{
        ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        
        ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
        
        env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(params);
        
        DataSet<String> text = env.readTextFile(params.get("input"));
        
        DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> tokenized = text.map(new Tokenizer());
        
        DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts = tokenized.groupBy(new int[] {0}).sum(1);
        
        if(params.has("output")) {
            counts.writeAsCsv(params.get("output"), "\n", " ");
            
            env.execute("Wordcount example");
        }
    }
    
    public static final class Tokenizer implements MapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>{
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> map(String value){
            return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(value, Integer.valueOf(1));
        }
    }
}
```

I have exported the jar for this class, and have added Wordcount as the main class while exporting jar.

I am using this command to run the exported jar: flink run ~/Desktop/FlinkDemo.jar --input inputfile.txt --output flinkoutput

I am still getting this error: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend

Please guide me in this.

Comment: H, welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please specify how you package your jar ? Thank you.

Comment: @MikalaiLushchytski I have packaged my jar by using export in Eclipse, wherein I am exporting the Wordcount java file, following below steps:

Screen 1. Add .classpath and .project
Screen 2. Check "Export class files with compile errors and compile warnings" boxes
Screen 3. "Generate the manifest file" & "Seal some packages" checked, and "Wordcount" selected as the Main class. Finish

Answer (score 0):

Is your jar really big? I fear that you have bundled Flink itself, which is not working well. It's usually generate a fatjar with [Maven/Gradle/Sbt/... without provided dependencies](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/project-configuration.html).